# Pandas vs Collections: Speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have used pandas historically because of its flexibility, simplicity, and because I had some experience in R. And I didn't really think I was giving up that much in terms of speed... but doing a few a/b comparisons for fun today have me scratching my head a little.

I'll use collections a bit but when I'm doing any sort of data science I just naturally gravitate toward pandas because it's felt like a pretty safe move. But is pandas fast enough? I'm not sure... I'm thinking I may have been sloppy in many cases. These are pretty big differences:

```
%%timeit
file = "Ex_Files_Python_Efficiently/Exercise Files/chapter2/02_05/goldmedals.txt"
df = pd.read_table(file,header=None, names=['year','athlete','team','event'])

def clean_event(name):
    return ' '.join(word for word in name.split() if word not in ['men', 'women'])

df['event'] = df.apply(lambda x: clean_event(x['event']), axis=1)
df.pivot_table(values='team', index='event', columns='athlete', aggfunc='nunique').sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

>>> 29.4 ms ± 285 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

now using collections:

```
%%timeit
file = "Ex_Files_Python_Efficiently/Exercise Files/chapter2/02_05/goldmedals.txt"
Medal = collections.namedtuple('medal',['year','athlete','team','event'])
medals = [Medal(*line.strip().split('\t')) for line in open(file, 'r')]

d = collections.defaultdict(set)

def howmany(tup):
    return len(tup[1])
def clean_event(name):
    return ' '.join(word for word in name.split() if word not in ['men', 'women'])

for medal in medals:
    d[medal.athlete].add(clean_event(medal.event))
sorted(d.items(), key=howmany, reverse=True)

>>> 2.94 ms ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Wow! Am I missing something major here? I'm pretty sure it's the df.apply that eats up the processing power (clean_event is not written in cython and even if so I think it would still have to come back to python to complete the join).

Has anyone here experienced similar a/b testing or can someone point me in a direction to dig in here a little more? I've found bits and pieces on SO over time but would love any nuggets of wisdom some of the more experienced folks have stumbled upon...

**EDIT:**
Changed clean_event() to a list comprehension. Still figuring out if I should stay in pandas for the pivot table, which adds abt 13ms.

```
%%timeit
from typing import List
file = "Ex_Files_Python_Efficiently/Exercise Files/chapter2/02_05/goldmedals.txt"
df = pd.read_table(file,header=None, names=['year','athlete','team','event'])

def clean_event(names: List[str]):
    return [' '.join(word for word in name.split() if word not in ['men', 'women']) for name in names]

df['event'] = clean_event(df['event'].values)
df.pivot_table(values='team', index='event', columns='athlete', aggfunc='nunique').sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
>>> 16.3 ms ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**FINAL EDIT:** I got rid of the pivot table and used a groupby(), which cuts some of the unnecessary operations out. Get us pretty close.

```
%%timeit
from typing import List
file = "Ex_Files_Python_Efficiently/Exercise Files/chapter2/02_05/goldmedals.txt"
df = pd.read_table(file,header=None, names=['year','athlete','team','event'])

def clean_event(names: List[str]):
    return [' '.join(word for word in name.split() if word not in ['men', 'women']) for name in names]

df['event'] = clean_event(df['event'].values)
df.groupby('athlete').nunique().sort_values('event', ascending=False)['event']
>>> 7.67 ms ± 64.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My final work here is shown here: https://github.com/bejoinka/playground

Comment: Sorry to break it to you but pandas is not nearly as optimised for string operations as it is numeric. You're better off sticking to python on this one.

Comment: That makes sense... figured it had to do with the text. I'll do a little playing around with numpy-driven stuff and see if I run into the same differences in speed.

Comment: you will see some improvements if you work with the `np.char` or `np.core.defchararray` submodules. However, list comprehensions in my experience have by far been the fastest.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure it's the df.apply that eats up the processing power " `df.apply` is essentially a convenience function around a python-level for-loop. It is the sort of "last resort" if you cannot figure out how to use built-in vectorized operations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, changing clean_event() from scalar to vector is huge time saver... especially as we get to larger data sets! Pivot is still slow.

Comment: @JBB that is *not a vectorized operation*, you are using a list comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would you structure it?

Comment: Pulling df[‘event’].values from the df is vectorized, no? Help me understand how you would perform vectorized operation to txt

Comment: You are using a numpy data structure, but not taking advantage of any of the built in vectorised operations. Unfortunately, there is not a lot of support for vectorised operations on string data, because you are typically using dtyoe=object, which removes most of the advantage of numpy to begin with